# Graphical GRUB editor for Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: grub2

I wanted to ask what graphical GRUB editors are there for the latest Ubuntu release (13.10)? **And how do I install one?** I searched through the Ubuntu Software Center but I can't find anything there.

Please provide very clear and basic instructions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Grub Customizer.  The Grub Customizer PPA now is available for Ubuntu 13.10.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: it is important to note that when a new system is installed, it usually re-installs the grub files, which are then the ones that determine the boot menu. in such a case, Grub Customizer  has to be installed in this latter system, while changes made with GC installed on a Linux/Ubuntu that existed before the latest Linux installation will not work

Comment: Appears stale (tested Ubuntu 17.04)
`E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/adabbas/1stppa/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found`

Comment: @JonathanLeaders I've updated the PPA for 17.04.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The PPA has moved as of Ubuntu 17.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then run with

```
grub-customizer
```